# Naturally Occurring Vegetable Oil?

Tags: terminology

Is it possible for vegetable oil to occur naturally, without being extracted? Along the same lines, it it possible for Hexane to occur naturally?

Comment: **Hexane** is present in volatile fractions of various plant species (e.g. apples, orange juice, guava fruit, roasted filberts, heated sweet potato and sage) and mushrooms (e.g. porcini and shiitake). It is also present in scallops.

Answer (score 1):

Vegetable oil is extracted from plant. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_oil), the term "vegetable oil" can be narrowly defined as referring only to plant oils that are liquid at room temperature,

So, answer is **no.**

If it occurs naturally than we will not call it vegetable oil.